# could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)

Tags: python, pip, mediapipe

Please help me out to get rid of this error while installing the mediapipe library in python 3.7.9 .

I have tried upgrading pip version but nothing so far seems to help

My current pip version is 21.3.1

I am running Windows 7 (32 bit) machine

Comment: What is your pip version?

Comment: @WilfredAlmeida I have updated question with my pip version

Comment: Try downgrading your pip version to 20.1.1

Comment: Try ```pip install mediapipe==0.8.9```. Is your OS 32 bit?

Comment: I have tried downgrading to lower versions but it didn't help

Comment: I have used `pip install mediapipe==0.8.9` also, the problem still persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please note that MediaPipe Python PyPI officially supports the 64-bit version of Python 3.7 and above on the following OS:
> x86_64 Linux 
> x86_64 macOS 10.15+
> amd64 Windows

Find details From the official docs of mediapipe [here](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/troubleshooting.html#python-pip-install-failure)

You'll have to run python and pip binary above 3.7 on a 64-bit OS. If your OS is unsupported/this doesn't work, you'll have to build the python mediapipe package. Follow the steps from official docs [here](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/python.html#building-mediapipe-python-package)

if you are building the package, also make sure you have opencv pre-installed. You can use the following command to install OpenCV

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Building the pipelone might seem overwelhming from a beginner perspective, however just read and follow the clearly mentioned steps and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Apple Silicon (M1, M2) etc you might see this problem.

At the time of writing (June 2022) there is no official binary release of Mediapipe for Apple Silicon.

According to https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3277 they are working on this and will support it "in the next release".

In the mean time there is a 3rd party build (linked in the issue above) which can be installed like this:

```
pip install mediapipe-silicon
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that pip packages were outdated. So, my solution was:
(i) First check outdated pip packages -

```
pip list --outdated
```

(ii) Next, update the pip packages. For Windows 10/11 -

```
pip freeze | %{$_.split('==')[0]} | %{pip install --upgrade $_}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by tried all version of pip. It worked with:
pip3.10.exe version on my device(Windows)

if you ask "how can you tried another versions?" like this

```
C:\Users\aykutatmaca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip3.10.exe install mediapipe
```

**first part of the command**(C:\Users\aykutatmaca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip3.10.exe) **is location of pip**,

**Second is** (install) 
**Third one is** (mediapipe)

Answer (score 1):

Mediapipe is running on python 3.10.9 64-bit so you can use 3.10.9 interpreter
i use it and solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

The only version that worked for me was python 3.7.0 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade pip and retry:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install mediapipe
```

2. If upgrade doesn't work, try installing mediapipe directly from the GitHub repository:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/google/mediapipe
```

3. If you are on Windows, try using the pre-compiled mediapipe wheels:

```
pip install mediapipe-gpu==0.8.8.1 # for GPU support
pip install mediapipe==0.8.8.1 # without GPU
```

Comment: If you need to ask questions to provide an answer you should get them first via comments.

Answer (score -2):

Mediapipe is running on python 3.10.9 64-bit so you can use 3.10.9 interpreter